# Google apps script Counter function

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to run below Javascript code in Google Apps Script. But I was getting a syntax error in 3rd line. 
Input: Array
ex: `var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'];` 
Output: Object similar to Python Counter 
`{ "a": 5, "b": 3, "c": 2 }`

```
function Counter(array) {  //function returns a counter of the input array.
  var count = {};
  array.forEach(val => count[val] = (count[val] || 0) + 1);
  return count;
}
```

My original question was to seek a help me to identify the error.
The error of the above function is the arrow function which was identified by two users(@theMaster and @tehhowch). 
Then I created the below function which works in JavaScript but getting an error in Google Apps Script.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "forEach" of undefined. (line 182, file "Code")

```
function createCounter(array) {  //function returns a counter of the input array.
  var countv = {};
  array.forEach( function(val)
    {countv[val] = (countv[val] || 0) + 1;
  });
return countv;
};
```

`var list = [40, 40, 10, 60, 60, 60, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40, 20]`
`Logger.log(createCounter(list));`

Expected output: `{ "10": 6, "20": 1, "30": 2, "40": 3, "60": 4 }`

I appreciate someone can help me with this.

Comment: Arrow syntax `=>` is not supported. Use regular function syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Javascript code not working in Google docs due to arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626679/simple-javascript-code-not-working-in-google-docs-due-to-arrow-function)

Comment: @tehhowch Now I am getting an error. "TypeError: Cannot call method "forEach" of undefined."                                                                          
function Counter(array) { //function returns a counter of the input array. var count = {}; array.forEach( function(val) {count[val] = (count[val] || 0) + 1; }); return count; }

Comment: Your problem is in your code that calls `Counter`

Comment: @tehhowch I get the same error after changing the function name.            
 "TypeError: Cannot call method "forEach" of undefined. (line 183, file "Code")".                                                                                              
 `function createCounter(array) {  //function returns a counter of the input array.
  var countv = {};
  array.forEach( function(val) 
    {countv[val] = (countv[val] || 0) + 1;
  
  });
  return countv;
}

var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
Logger.log(createCounter(list));`

Comment: If you are having a different error than you originally had, either edit your question to detail the issue, or ask a new question with the appropriate information. Since no one has tried to answer your original question, an edit is appropriate. Be detailed, and show your research too.

Comment: You need to show the minimal complete code you use to call your counter function. Why? Because you are giving your counter function a bad argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and I get: `{60=4.0, 40=3.0, 30=2.0, 20=1.0, 10=6.0}`

```
function testCounter(){
  var s=createCounter([40, 40, 10, 60, 60, 60, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40, 20]);
  Logger.log(s);
}

function createCounter(array) {  //function returns a counter of the input array.
  var countv = {};
  array.forEach(function(val){
    countv[val] = (countv[val] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return countv;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me to improve the **createCounter(array)** function to get the output similar to this  `{ "10": 6, "20": 1, "30": 2, "40": 3, "60": 4 }` . Same function works fine in JavaScript.

Comment: Here's what I get in the Chrome console: `{10: 6, 20: 1, 30: 2, 40: 3, 60: 4}`