# Google AppScript - Merge arrays based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've looked through a lot of similar answers to this question but have not gotten any solutions to work.

I have two separate functions with one array each, that I populate like this:

1. `folderMap.push([{siteurl: filename,logid: fileurl}]);`
2. `mapping.push([{siteurl: x[0],shareddriveid: x[1]}]);`

I want to have a third function that I want to match the items based on `siteurl` and put that object in one array while putting any matches that don't have all three items (a siteurl, logid, and shareddriveid) into another. The source arrays will be different sizes. My current code looks like this:

```
  const combined = folderMap.concat(mapping);
  const applicable = combined.filter(i => i[0]['siteurl'] && i[0]);
  const byTeamUrl = combined.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc[item['siteurl']] = Object.assign(acc[item['siteurl']] || {}, item);
      if (item.length > 2) {
        Logger.log(item);
        }
      return acc;
  }, {});
```

Nothing is output, but I know that there should be at least three items that are in both source arrays. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pushing an array to my object when I should have just been pushing fields. I also reformatted my code so the same object was passed from function 1 to function 2 where function 2 used `findIndex` to update the value.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script doesn't currently support ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Hence your arrow functions will not work.

Per Google's docs: [Basic JavaScript Features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51628532/8245557

However, you can develop for Apps Script in TypeScript using clasp: [Develop Apps Script using TypeScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript)

Comment: Let's assume I ran this outside of GAS where I could use ES6 - would this work?