# Syntax Error with `e.drive.selectedItems.forEach((itm, i) => {`

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

If write a function like this:

```
function onMyDriveItemSelected(e) {
  var s = '';
  if (e.drive.selectedItems.length > 0) {
    //e.drive.selectedItems.forEach(function (itm,i) {
    e.drive.selectedItems.forEach((itm, i) => {  <= This line gives me syntax error
      if (i > 0) { s += '<br><br>'; }
      s += Utilities.formatString(' %s<br> ', itm.id);
    });
  }
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var infotxt = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(s);
  section.addWidget(infotxt);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}
```

I get the above syntax error as identified by the arrow

If I write the function like this:

```
function onMyDriveItemSelected(e) {
  var s = '';
  if (e.drive.selectedItems.length > 0) {
    e.drive.selectedItems.forEach(function (itm,i) {
    //e.drive.selectedItems.forEach((itm, i) => {
      if (i > 0) { s += '<br><br>'; }
      s += Utilities.formatString(' %s<br> ', itm.id);
    });
  }
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var infotxt = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(s);
  section.addWidget(infotxt);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}
```

I don't get a syntax error.  I'm using the new editor with the V8 engine enabled.  Not being a long time user of arrow functions I thought may be one of you could explain the syntax error.  I've tried every combination of things but nothing seems to work with arrow notation. It's interesting to note that there are none of those little icons that normally appear when you have syntax errors on the screen but it still generates a syntax error message.

The function is the `onItemsSelectedTrigger` handler for a workspace drive addon.

Just to be clear my question is about the syntax error.  I have a working script for the addon.  That's not the problem.  I just don't understand why moving away from arrow notation was necessary.

> One of my biggest issues on Stack Over Flow is not reading the question and jumping into the answer before I thoroughly read the question and I can see now that others of us have the same problem.  The problem boils down to explaining why I get a syntax error from the new editor running V8.  It boils down to the difference between two lines.

This line works:

```
`e.drive.selectedItems.forEach(function (itm,i) {`
```

This line gives me a syntax error:

```
`e.drive.selectedItems.forEach((itm, i) => {`
```

The rest of the line is the same:

```
`if (i > 0) { s += '<br><br>'; }
      s += Utilities.formatString(' %s<br> ', itm.id);
    });`
```

and as far as I know the arrow function is written correctly.  If I'm wrong please inform me.

One of the answer's I received was probably prompted from the recent comment addition to the comment box informing us not to answer questions in the comment box and a newbie to SO provided a question in answer to suggest that I move away from Rhino which, arguably, should probably have been given in a comment.

The other was a long time SO volunteer who jumped to the conclusion that I was having trouble getting a drive addon to work and provided me with a good answer to the wrong question.  Which I fully understand having done the same thing all to often myself.

After having the question only tagged with google-apps script I decided to add the JavaScript tag assuming that someone on there would likely be able to see the difference.  But alas that hasn't worked either.  So I guess I will assume that it's a new editor issue and move on.  Either way I'm not going to bother create an issue because the code is working proving me with the id of my files without having to open them and if the editor continues to provide erroneous errors then so be it. I'll learn to live with them.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626679/simple-javascript-code-not-working-in-google-docs-due-to-arrow-function

Comment: I see that Tanaike did something similar to what I did.  I'm wondering why the arrow functions don't work.  I think they're correct.

Comment: Yes, they're correct. My best guess is that you're using Rhino engine, which does not support ES6  (arrow functions were added in ES6). 
Check this link to make sure you have V8 runtime enabled - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime

Comment: Please add more details... the textual error message , a sample of `e`

Comment: If it gave me more information I would have provided but all I know is that I have a textual error with a line number.  Either you know the error by looking at the arrow notation or you don't.